# Browsing datadirectory for SQL Server database does not work

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have hardcoded the data directory for the database. Since I want to avoid it, I have decided to use the `FolderBrowserDialog` and store the dialog string into the application settings.

This is the hardcoded code snippet, which can open the SQL connection:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"C:\Users\Osman\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CompanyWPF\CompanyWPF\");

try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Produkt.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        con.Open();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

But when I'm using the stored string from the application settings:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory",@"" + Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);

try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=@|DataDirectory|\Produkt.mdf;Integrated Security=True") )
    {
        con.Open();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

then the following error occurs:

> Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.

I have set a breakpoint, and the stored string from the application setting has the value:

```
C:\\Users\\Osman\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\CompanyWPF\\CompanyWPF\\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not sure what you are going to do but i think here is the problem

```
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=@|DataDirectory|\Produkt.mdf;Integrated Security=True") )
```

Use This Instead

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Produkt.mdf;Integrated Security=True") )
```

Note : Remove @ From this "@|DataDirectory| "